# Can you add doxygen tags for CMake scripts/files?

Tags: cmake, doxygen

Basically, can I add doxygen-style tags for CMake files (mostly, I'd like to add file and author tags to stay consistent with the existing C++ code). Something like

```
###
###@file Stuff.CMake
###@author  Bob Smith <bob.smit@nonubuisness.com>
###
###
###@section EDITS
###
### 2013.10.02 Created
###
###@section DESCRIPTIONS
### Does stuff
###
###@section License
###Copyright Info, License, ect
###
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

###
###@brief Macro that does something
###
###@param bar thing to do something to
###
macro foo(bar)
endmacro()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing what would work is adding *.CMake to the FILE_PATTERNS option in the doxyfile and comment as follwing:

```
#///
#///@file Stuff.CMake
#///@author  Bob Smith <bob.smit@nonubuisness.com>
#/// etc.
```

One thing what might be an issue is that Doxygen doesn't know the CMake syntax...